# Is it possible to give name to Quasar Uploader in <form>

Tags: c#, .net-core, quasar-framework

I have a `<form>` where I am using Vue.js and Quasar, and submits in as a HTML form in asp .net core 3.1
The problem is when I am using Quasar *Uploader* (https://quasar.dev/vue-components/uploader).

The functionality works fine, but when I submit the form (post i C# and .net core).
I cant get the the file in the controller.

As you can see from this example: https://codepen.io/cbrown___/pen/GRZwpxw

When the *Uploader* is rendered it does not have the attribute **name**. From the example above you have this input:
`<input tabindex="-1" type="file" title="" class="q-uploader__input overflow-hidden absolute-full">`.

I guess that is why I cant get it from my Controller. How can I solve this when I am using .net Core 3.1 to submit this form?
And I see no good solutinos in letting people upload files through my API before  the record is created.
Is it a option here I do not see?

EDIT:
The `<input>` is on the plus-icon. So by using inspect elements you should be able to see that no name occurs.

EXAMPLE CODE:
HTML

```
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-sm row items-start">
      <q-uploader
        url="http://localhost:4444/upload"
        style="max-width: 300px"
      ></q-uploader>

      <q-uploader
        url="http://localhost:4444/upload"
        color="teal"
        flat
        bordered
        style="max-width: 300px"
      ></q-uploader>

      <q-uploader
        url="http://localhost:4444/upload"
        label="Upload files"
        color="purple"
        square
        flat
        bordered
        style="max-width: 300px"
      ></q-uploader>

      <q-uploader
        url="http://localhost:4444/upload"
        label="No thumbnails"
        color="amber"
        text-color="black"
        no-thumbnails
        style="max-width: 300px"
      ></q-uploader>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app'
})
```

Comment: It's not gonna be possible to help you without a [mre]. Notice also that your codepen link takes you to a blank editor.

Comment: Sorry for the link. Added also how to see/reproduce the error in codepen.

Answer (score 0):

If any body else need this I ended up with using this:

`:name="'file_description[' + index + ']'"`

That way each one got one name...and from another array I knew how many file_description it would be.